# dired-recent - not show correct recent visited directories

Tags: dired, recentf

```
Linux Mint 20
Emacs 27
dired, dired-recent
```

Steps:

```
1. "recentf-mode" is turn on
2. Go to directory "Download". Use "Jump to bookmark" (C-x r b). Input "Download"
3. As result in Dired mode open folder "/home/alexeij/Downloads/"
4. Go to directory "Temp". Use "Jump to bookmark" (C-x r b).  Input "Temp"
5. As result in Dired mode open folder "/home/alexeij/Temp/"
6. Go to directory "dev". Use  "Jump to bookmark" (C-x r b).  Input "dev"
7. As result in Dired mode open folder "/home/alexeij/dev/"
```

Nice. Now I want to see history of recent visited directories **in chronological way**.

So I use:

```
dired-recent-open
```

But in minibuffer show another directories.

Why?

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Is the use of bookmarks important to the recipe here? If not, please simplify it. Also: do you see the same thing if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your file to find the problem. Is `dired-recent` a 3rd-party library?

Comment: @Drew Yes, this is a 3rd party library - https://github.com/vifon/dired-recent.el

Comment: If you don't get an answer here for that library, you might contact its maintainer. That feature might not yet be available with that library.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus). It offers these commands for use with recentf:

- diredp-add-file-to-recentf
- diredp-add-this-to-recentf
- diredp-dired-recent-dirs  `C-x D r`
- diredp-dired-recent-dirs-other-window  `C-x 4 D r`
- diredp-dired-recent-files  `C-x D R`
- diredp-dired-recent-files-other-window  `C-x 4 D R`
- diredp-do-add-to-recentf
- diredp-do-remove-from-recentf
- diredp-remove-file-from-recentf
- diredp-remove-this-from-recentf

In particular, `diredp-dired-recent-dirs` should do what I think you're looking for:

> **`diredp-dired-recent-dirs`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
> [`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el).
>
> It is bound to `menu-bar subdir diredp-dired-recent-dirs`, `C-x D r`.
>
> `(diredp-dired-recent-dirs BUFFER &optional ARG FILES)`
>
> Open Dired in `BUFFER`, showing recently visited directories.
>
> Like `diredp-dired-recent-files`, but limited to recent directories.
> A directory is recent if any of its files is recent.

The doc of `diredp-dired-recent-files`, which the above refers to, tells you about using a prefix arg. Note that `C-u` or `0` as prefix arg prompts you for the `ls` switches to use, and **you can specify chronological order** with the switches (e.g. switch `t`).

You can also just use option `diredp-default-sort-arbitrary-function` to sort the entries however you want.

> **`diredp-dired-recent-files`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in [`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el).
>
> It is bound to `C-x D R`.
>
> `(diredp-dired-recent-files BUFFER &optional ARG FILES)`
>
> Open Dired in BUFFER, showing recently visited files and directories.
>
> You are prompted for `BUFFER` (default: `Recently Visited Files`).
>
> With a numeric prefix arg you can enter names of recent files to
> include or exclude.
>
> No prefix arg or a plain prefix arg (`C-u`, `C-u C-u`, etc.) means
> list all of the recently used files.
>
> **With a prefix arg:**
>
> - **If 0, `-`, or plain (`C-u`) then you are prompted for the `ls`
>   switches to use.**
> - If not plain (`C-u`) then:
> - If >= 0 then the files to include are read, one by one.
> - If  < 0 then the files to exclude are read, one by one.
>
> When entering files to include or exclude, use `C-g` to end.
>
> The file listing is **sorted by option
> `diredp-default-sort-arbitrary-function`**, if non-`nil`.  If `nil` (the
> default) then the listing is in reverse chronological order of opening
> or writing files you access.
>
> Use `g` to revert the buffer, as usual.  If you use it without a
> prefix arg then the same files are relisted.  A prefix arg is handled
> as for `C-x D R` itself.
>
> When called from Lisp:
>
> - `ARG` corresponds to the raw prefix arg.
> - `FILES` is passed to `diredp--dired-recent-files-1`.  It is used only
>   when the command is used as part of the `revert-buffer-function`.